# SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' when import monorepo package

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vite, monorepo

I import package in vite.config.ts, it will throw syntax error

[image]

But it can be successfully imported in app.vue, I don't know why

my files tree

```
- packages
  - components
  - yep-ui
- playground
  - vite.config.ts
```

Here is my repo.
[the code trigger question](https://github.com/ylw5/yep-ui/blob/56f455738289d312ff082bfb10ddac6b69852f87/playground/vite.config.ts#L11)
I would appreciate if someone can help me.